# ASCIIMath: JS method to get TeX value of rendered expression?

Tags: javascript, mathjax, asciimath

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaya3znh/) is using [ASCIIMath](http://asciimath.org/) to show the expression *1+x^2*.

How can I get TeX value of ASCIIMath expression after it has been rendered? I want to save that value into myTeX div?

Is there an ASCIIMath method or [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/).Hub method to retrieve TeX?

**HTML + JavaScript:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=AM_HTMLorMML-full">  
 </script>

 <div id="myExpr">`1+x^2`</div>
 <div id="myTeX"></div>

 <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({ 
           messageStyle: 'none', 
           tex2jax: { preview: 'none'}   
      });
 </script>
```

### **UPDATE:**

Here is how its done:

**JavaScript:**

```
 <script src="ASCIIMathTeXImg.js"></script>

 <script>
      var x = AMTparseAMtoTeX('1+5/4^2');
      console.log(x);
 </script>
```

Comment: Are you looking for the asciimath source or a conversion of asciimath to TeX syntax?

Comment: I am wondering if there is method built into ASCIIMath or MATHJax to convert rendered asciimath to TeX syntax?

Comment: Not the rendering but there's a php script in the asciimath repository for converting asciimath to LaTeX, https://github.com/asciimath/asciimathml/tree/master/asciimath-based. There's nothing build into MathJax yet, see https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1124

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed. Your comment is the answer. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it, thanks again!

Comment: Glad that's all. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to deal with the rendering but with the ASCIImath source.

The asciimath repository includes a PHP script for converting asciimath to LaTeX, see https://github.com/asciimath/asciimathml/tree/master/asciimath-based.

There is nothing built into MathJax yet but a feature request at https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1124.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I have upvoted and accepted your answer.